# Unexpected expected value (mean) in modeling AR(1) with for-loop in R

Tags: r, mean, modeling, standard-deviation, autoregressive-models

(reproducible example added)
I tried to code the AR(1) model Y<sub>t</sub>=0.6Y<sub>t-1</sub>+V<sub>t</sub> (V<sub>t</sub> ~ N(0,1)).

```
# Function that makes (mean,sd) of a sample drawn from population exactly 
# same with those of the population
rnorm2 <- function(n,mean,sd) { mean + sd*scale(rnorm(n)) } 

N <- 1388; ro <- 0.6; a <- 0
set.seed(1)
v <- ts(rnorm2(N,0,1)) # white noise, v~N(0,1)
c(mean(v),sd(v)) # 1.160729e-17 = 0; 1.000000e+00 = 1
y <- ts(rep(0,N))  # y[1]:=0 defined    
for (t in 2:N){  y[t] <- a + ro*y[t-1]+v[t] }
```

After arranging `rnorm` function in the desired way as `rnorm2` as above, I expected to obtain the mean and standard deviation of y as follows:

Mean(Y<sub>t</sub>) = alfa/(1-ρ)

```
a/(1-ro) # 0
```

StdDev(Y<sub>t</sub>)=sqrt[sd(v)<sup>2</sup>/(1-ρ<sup>2</sup>)]

```
sqrt(sd(v)^2/(1-(0.6)^2)) # 1.25
```

But, I get:

```
c(mean(y),sd(y)) # 0.002486451 1.227402426
```

Why are those mean and standard deviation different (0.002486451<>0; 1.227402426<>1.25)?

Comment: That's like... The entire reason the field of statistics exists...

Comment: You took a random sample. Do you expect it to perfectly match the expected values?

Comment: @Dason, I took random v (white noise), and its mean is exactly same with that of the population it was drawn (`mean(v)=0`!). Hence, just as the exact equivalence of `c(mean(v),sd(v))` with its population, I expect `c(mean(y),sd(y))` to be same.

Comment: @Dason, If I hadn't defined `rnorm2`, your reasoning would be valid: `set.seed(1); c(mean(ts(rnorm(1388,mean=0,sd=1))), sd(ts(rnorm(1388,mean=0,sd=1))))
# [1] -0.01590441<>0  1.03055089<>1. `

Comment: Ok but your reasoning is still flawed. Just because the expected value is 0 didn't mean the finite sample mean will be 0. Take generating two values. Ignore the standard deviation. Say to get mean 0 we use -1 and 1. Then your values for y will be 0, 0+.6*0+ -1= -1, 0 + .6*(-1) +1 = .4. so you have 0, -1, .4. Those don't have a sample mean of 0. Your process won't give 0 as the mean by default.

Comment: @Dason, Many many thanks for your clear concrete example. You can write it as an answer. I got your logic.